# Commented line of code is throwing an exception

Tags: java, spring

I have a perfectly logical exception being thrown: I have a workbook I create, then try to call `getSheetAt(0)` before creating the sheet. What is puzzling is that I commented out this code, yet I am getting an Illegal Argument Exception on the same line of code that is commented. It is even pointing to this line of code in the stack trace, how is this possible?? When I copy in my code stack overflow is not even reading it as code!

I've tried saving all the files, stopping then cleaning my server, then starting it back up with the latest project loaded onto it. This file is called FileUploadController and line 40 is being read, which is the following

```
    //  XSSFSheet outputSheet = outputBook.getSheetAt(0);

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadMultipleFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String uploadMultipleFileHandler(@RequestParam("CFfile") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        File outputFile = null;

//      XSSFWorkbook outputBook = new XSSFWorkbook();
//      XSSFSheet outputSheet = outputBook.getSheetAt(0);
//      XSSFRow outRow;
//      XSSFCell outCell;
//      DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

        System.out.println("calling upload multiple file handler");
        System.out.println("file size: " + file.getSize());
        System.out.println("file content type: " + file.getContentType());
        System.out.println("file name " + file.getOriginalFilename());
        System.out.println("file is there? : " + file.isEmpty());
```

---

```
Expected: Sysout statements are read
```

---

```
Actual: 
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring-dispatcher] in context with path [/XDE_V1.2] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Sheet index (0) is out of range (0..-1)] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Sheet index (0) is out of range (0..-1)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.validateSheetIndex(XSSFWorkbook.java:1043)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.getSheetAt(XSSFWorkbook.java:834)
    at com.cognizant.idw.xde.controllers.FileUploadController.uploadMultipleFileHandler(FileUploadController.java:40)
```

Comment: See what outputBook.getNumberOfSheets() yields.

Comment: If you are commenting the code, and it is being executed anyway, it seems to be a cache issue. Clean your projects and server, rebuild your apps and publish them again. Also make sure your new artifact is being published, if needed force the removal in the file system.

Comment: Clean your project and rebuild.  Commented code does not throw exceptions.